# Не отображает флэшку в IE9

Tags: flash-player, flash, internet-explorer, swf

Работает в Firefox, Opera, Chrome самых свежих версий. А в осле не хочет.

```
<object style="margin-left:-40px;" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=7,0,0,0" width="600" height="206" id="player1" align="middle">

<param name="movie" value="ContiRA2-pres.swf"/>

<param name="menu" value="false"/>

<param name="quality" value="high"/>

<param name="bgcolor" value="111111"/>

<embed src="video/ContiRA2-pres.swf" menu="false" quality="high" bgcolor="111111" width="600" height="206" name="player" align="middle" allowScriptAccess="sameDomain" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer"/>

</object>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

всегда вот так вставляю, вроде везде прокатывает:

```
<object style="margin-left:-40px;" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" width="600" height="206" id="player1" align="middle">
    <param name="movie" value="video/ContiRA2-pres.swf" />
    <param name="quality" value="high" />
    <param name="bgcolor" value="111111"/>
    <param name="menu" value="false"/>
    <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
    <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
    <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
    <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="video/ContiRA2-pres.swf" width="600" height="206">
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="wmode" value="opaque" />
        <param name="swfversion" value="6.0.65.0" />
        <param name="expressinstall" value="Scripts/expressInstall.swf" />
    </object>
</object>
```

ps: у тебя 2 разных путя к файлу записаны

Comment: два пути, а не путя

Comment: я прогер, а не лингвист, мне главное чтоб было понятно

Comment: благодарю! работает

Comment: Это, конечно, главное. Но лучше, когда это сделано грамотно.

Comment: в принципе согласен